# coffeelint.json syntax checking not being picked up by emacs

Tags: emacs, coffeescript

I am using coffeemode in emacs and the relevant parts of my init.el look like this;

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(coffee-tab-width 2)
 '(flymake-coffee-coffeelint-configuration-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/coffeelint.json"))(require 'coffee-mode)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.coffee$" . coffee-mode))
(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook 'flymake-coffee-load)
(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook 'company-mode)
(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook 'flymake-mode)
(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook
          'disable-electric-indent-mode))
```

My coffeelint file is not being used by the linter as the warnings for things like max_line_length are not picking up the overriden values.

Comment: Better use `"\\.coffee\\'"` for `auto-mode-alist` since `$` matches not just the end of string but also the end of line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually stumbled across this which works for me:

```
(setq coffee-tab-width 2)
(custom-set-variables
 '(coffee-tab-width 2)
 '(flycheck-coffeelintrc "~/.emacs.d/coffeelint.json"))

(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook 'flymake-mode)
```